# google pay and apple pay in flutter using pay pacakage

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, payment-gateway, google-pay

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTJw0.png)i am using google pay  as my international  payment method  in my app using  pay: ^1.1.0 package i am seeing the pay with google option in my emulator but not in real device in debug mode also what may be the reason and how can i test it  whre do i find the card  for google payment  is picture is of real devide and second is of emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cuov.png)

i was expecting to show the button in real device
String os = Platform.operatingSystem;

```
   const Center(
                      child: Text(
                    "or Pay with ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: CgFontSize.headerThree,
                      color: CgColor.ghostWhite,
                    ),
                  )),
                  Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Platform.isIOS
                            ? ApplePayButton(
                                paymentConfiguration:
                                    PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
                                        defaultApplePay),
                                paymentItems: _paymentItems,
                                style: ApplePayButtonStyle.black,
                                type: ApplePayButtonType.buy,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                                onPaymentResult: ((result) {
                                  debugPrint("Payment Result $result");
                                  log(result.toString());
                                  BaseRequest().applePay(
                                    packageId: "",
                                    amount: "",
                                    paymentMethod: "",
                                    token: "",
                                  );
                                }),
                                loadingIndicator: const Center(
                                  child: LoadingProgressIndicator(),
                                ),
                              )
                            : GooglePayButton(
                                paymentConfiguration:
                                    PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
                                        defaultGooglePay),
                                paymentItems: _paymentItems,
                                type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                                onPaymentResult: ((result) {
                                  debugPrint("Payment Result $result");
                                  log(result.toString());
                                  BaseRequest().goglePay(
                                      packageId: "",
                                      amount: "",
                                      paymentMethod: "",
                                      token: "",
                                      productId: "");
                                }),
                                loadingIndicator: const Center(
                                  child: LoadingProgressIndicator(),
                                ),
                              ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

hear is my code

Comment: As for the availability of a card for Google Pay, it depends on the user's Google account settings and their location.

Comment: "gateway": "example",
            "gatewayMerchantId": "gatewayMerchantId"  what will be the    "gateway":  if i am using this pacakage